# foreach loop that include php files multiple times - acceptable?

Tags: php, if-statement, require

I have this function "processMessage($msg)" that processes string  based on the first few words in it (prefixes).

I pull lots of rows from the database and pass each $msg string through said function...

The caveat here is that, the function doesn't have the "if($prefix=='blah')" conditions, but rather it includes a bunch of php files that contains these conditions.

Why?

Because instead of hard coding a bunch of conditions in one function, I wanted to organize each condition through separate php files for portability, customization etc (Long story here)

So it basically looks like this (keeping code simple):

Main script loads rows from database and puts messages in an array $msg_r then loops through each msg as:

```
foreach (msg_r as $key=>$msg){
    processMsg($msg);
}
```

the  actual Processor function :

```
function processMsg($msg){

    $msg_r = explode(" ",$msg); // break apart message based on spaces .. eg. "reboot machine 30"
    //prepare prefixes
    $prefix1 = $msg_r[0];// reboot
    $prefix2 = $msg_r[1];// machine
    $prefix3 = $msg_r[3];// 30

    //process the above prefixes.. but instead of hard coding multiple if conditions here, load if else conditions from files. 
    require("condition1.php");
    require("condition2.php");
    require("condition3.php");
    //my actual require code is in a loop that loads all files found in a target directory


}
```

the conditions files are basically just php code of an if else condition for each purpose, eg:

```
if($prefix1 == 'reboot' and $prefix2 == 'machine') {
// do something
}
```

So it's a simple setup that seems to work during my tests, but I wonder if this is a "normal" or "acceptable" strategy, or if ya'll can suggest a different approach?

Regards to all

Comment: This seems like horrible style, and probably very poor performance because it has to read each file every time. You should define a function in the file, include it once, and then call the function.

Comment: yes, that's a very unusual approach. Why don't you call a normal function (or 3 in your case) instead of including/requiring a whole file in every loop?

Comment: I see what he's doing -- he doesn't want to hard-code the function names, he's just listing the directory and including all the files dynamically.

Comment: @Barmar - exactly mate. I need a dynamic way to add/remove conditions. the software is built for multiple client accounts on same base code, so each account will have their "prefix_processor" folder and inside it are a bunch of condition files (max 30 files i would assume). so it's basically for portability, if client wants a new condition, i can send a client 1 condition file only instead of having to dig into 1 file and might cause breakage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of functions, and have each include file define a function and push it onto the array. So the main script would contain:

```
$test_array = array();
require ("condition1.php");
require ("condition2.php");
...
```

and the include files would do:

```
$test_array[] = function($prefix1, $prefix2, $prefix3) {
    if ($prefix1 == 'reboot' && $prefix2 == 'machine') {
        // do something
    }
};
```

And your main function would be:

```
function processMsg($msg){
    global $test_array;

    $msg_r = explode(" ",$msg); // break apart message based on spaces .. eg. "reboot machine 30"
    //prepare prefixes
    $prefix1 = $msg_r[0];// reboot
    $prefix2 = $msg_r[1];// machine
    $prefix3 = $msg_r[3];// 30

    foreach ($test_array as $test) {
        $test($prefix1, $prefix2, $prefix3);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh wow, that's a beautiful approach man. thanks i will test this. btw, what if i do it in a way where I name the condition file based on my target prefix, then only load the condition file based on the prefix? basically sticking with my approach, but not having to load all condition files at every loop, but just the needed ones?

Comment: How you decide which file to load is irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: oh because your approach requires me to load all condition files before looping through each message, while my approach loads file within the loop (since it's in the loop where i extract the prefix for each messge) .

Comment: I see what you're saying. You could make `$test_array` more organized, perhaps make it a multidimensional array where the first dimension is an associative array containing target prefixes. Then you could just loop through a particular prefix.

Comment: ah yes that makes a lot of sense!  :) will do exactly that. will post feedback. thank you

Comment: Alright, got it working nicely this way. Thanks very much Barmar! You've helped me a lot.